# React Project: Safari seems to be rendering, but not painting elements?

Tags: reactjs, safari, rendering, mobile-safari

I'm rendering a list of cards that each display some data along with three rows that allow the user to navigate to a specific, expanded section of that card.

For some reason, Safari seems to be rendering the three navigation rows for each card, but they are white and transparent. I know they're rendered because I can still click on the space where the row would be and the navigation works as expected. It's just invisible.

This problem is not happening when using Chrome. It only happens on Safari: both on my desktop in the browser and when running Safari on iOS. There are no errors in the console.

Another strange puzzle piece is that when I inspect the element's in Safari they appear on the screen! Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmrgkfjthfxfwkp/Screen%20Recording%202020-09-29%20at%2011.30.32%20AM.mov?dl=0) to a video I took to show the behavior.

Any ideas???

Comment: if you are seeing this only on Safari and not on other browsers, then, you already have the answer. Its a Safari specific issue, and fixing it  will come down to studying Safari specific CSS issues and fixes with bootstrap or your CSS or theme if you are using it. Remember that each browser implements CSS things in its own way. in my own experience, I have found that Safari is a lot more strict in terms of standards and formats, and many times, a lot of CSS things dont work that well. this is just my experience and not a science/tech based thought.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. After a ton of digging yesterday, I finally found a couple similar issues. The comments instructed the same as you. Essentially I need to remove CSS until I find the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I took Jay's advice and started trimming CSS. Eventually I realized that the "update rows" had both display: "flex" and position: "relative" set. Once I removed position: "relative," which wasn't doing anything in the first place but must have been added by mistake, Safari rendered it perfectly.

TLDR: For Safari, display: "flex" and position: "relative" on the same div created rendering issues.

Comment: This anwser saves my day. I was using `display: flex` and `position: sticky` in the same `div` element. After changing `position` from `sticky` to `absolute`, it is rendering perfectly.